# one device controlling a number of devices actions

Tags: webos

I am making an app in which the administrator controls other devices in the same wi-fi network and controls the actions like viewing a document by the others,which, is the same as what the administrator is viewing....i need the code for this using zero-configuration networking

Answer (score 0):

The Developer Docs on the palm developer center are very good. This is the service you probably need to read up on and understand...

https://developer.palm.com/content/api/reference/services/zeroconf.html